# getting debit cedit and balance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the below query to the following information from table statement

```
SELECT [Statement_ID] as SID, t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
       t.Description, t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
     (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
      FROM Statement as x
      WHERE (x.date < t.date or
             x.date = t.date and x.[Statement_ID] <= t.[Statement_ID]
            ) AND
            x.CustID = t.CustID
     ) b
WHERE t.CustID ='48' and date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
ORDER BY t.date
```

out put

```
SID InvoiceID   Type            Date    Debit   Credit  Balance
176     51  Service Invoice 2015-08-29  500.00  0.00    500.00
462     51  Receipt Voucher 2015-09-07  0.00    500.00  0.00
107     76  Service Invoice 2015-09-28  1000.00 0.00    1000.00
165     208 Service Invoice 2015-09-28  500.00  0.00    1500.00
217     119 Service Invoice 2015-10-31  500.00  0.00    2000.00
459     76  Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  1500.00
460     208 Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  1000.00
461     119 Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  500.00
163     165 Service Invoice 2015-12-01  500.00  0.00    1000.00
458     165 Receipt Voucher 2015-12-22  0.00    500.00  500.00
44      224 Service Invoice 2015-12-31  500.00  0.00    1000.00
```

First how can i get each Receipt Voucher under it invoice

second when i have Receipt Voucher with same date of invoice how i can be sure it gets under Invoice using Statement_ID since Receipt Voucher is always entered after the invoice

the expected out put

order invoices by date and get it Receipt Voucher

```
S_ID    InvoiceID   Type    Date        Debit   Credit  Balance
176     51  Service Invoice 2015-08-29  500.00  0.00    500.00
462     51  Receipt Voucher 2015-09-07  0.00    500.00  0.00
107     76  Service Invoice 2015-09-28  1000.00 0.00    1000.00
459     76  Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  500.00
165     208 Service Invoice 2015-09-28  500.00  0.00    1000.00
460     208 Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  500.00
217     119 Service Invoice 2015-10-31  500.00  0.00    1000.00
461     119 Receipt Voucher 2015-11-21  0.00    500.00  500.00
163     165 Service Invoice 2015-12-01  500.00  0.00    1000.00
458     165 Receipt Voucher 2015-12-22  0.00    500.00  500.00
44      224 Service Invoice 2015-12-31  500.00  0.00    1000.00
```

Comment: hmm... this needs a more view on your schema; just to get result why can't you order by InvoiceID, Type, Date?

Comment: I'm with @techspider just change your order by.  InvoiceID should probably be first then Date

Comment: ok thanks i will try

Comment: That won't necessarily do it, you need date to take precedence, but you only need to consider date when the [Type] is 'Service Invoice'. I would turn your query into a CTE, create a second chained CTE to get a RowNumber() Over (Order By [Date]) for only the Service Invoice records and return the RowNumber value with the InvoiceID and then join this back to your first CTE on InvoiceID and then order by the RowNumber column (whatever you call it).

Comment: @JamieD77 if you look at the desired output it does't always work to use InvoiceID; for whatever reason InvoiceID 208 is out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this...

```
With    CTE1 AS
(
        SELECT [Statement_ID] as SID, t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
               t.Description, t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
        FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
             (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
              FROM Statement as x
              WHERE (x.date < t.date or
                     x.date = t.date and x.[Statement_ID] <= t.[Statement_ID]
                    ) AND
                    x.CustID = t.CustID
             ) b
        WHERE t.CustID ='48' and date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
),      CTE2 AS
(
        SELECT  Row_Number() Over (Order By [Date]) As priorityID,
                [InvoiceID]
        FROM    CTE1
        WHERE   [Type] = 'Service Invoice'
)
Select  c1.*
From    CTE1 c1
JOIN    CTE2 c2
        ON c1.[InvoiceID] = c2.[InvoiceID]
ORDER BY c2.priorityID, c1.[Date]
```

Comment: thanks but i am not sure how to use the solution i tried run it as query i get this error The column prefix 'CTE1' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
sorry i am not good at sql

Comment: Oops, try again. I didn't use the table alias properly when specifying the return values.

Comment: thanks but theirs one issue it not give values ordered by date

Comment: Ugh, try again. The InvoiceIDs should be ordered correctly, but I suppose the Types could've been in weird order as I didn't add it as another level.